# Template keeps redrawing, despite no change to the underlying data

Tags: meteor

can anyone tell me why the rendered Live HTML in this example keeps clearing then redrawing in an infinite loop? This example code maxes out the CPU on my laptop..

Environment:

- Meteor 0.3.7
- Mac OS Lion
- tested in Safari 5.1.7, Chrome Canary 22.0.1189, Chrome 21.0.1180, Firefox 11.0 & 13.0

initial project creation:

```
meteor create test
cd test
meteor add coffeescript
mv test.js test.coffee
meteor
```

test.coffee:

```
Records = new Meteor.Collection("records")

if Meteor.is_client
    Template.table.records = ->
        Records.find()
    Template.table.rowCount = ->
        Records.find().count()

if Meteor.is_server
    Meteor.startup ->
        if Records.find().count() is 0
            for i in [1..1000]
                Records.insert({some:"test", data: "just", to: "check"})
```

test.html:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> table}}
</body>

<template name="table">
    <table>
        <caption>{{rowCount}}</caption>
        {{#each records}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{some}}</td>
            <td>{{data}}</td>
            <td>{{to}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
  </table>  
</template>
```

Comment: i ran the same example code with various dataset sizes: the redrawing issue seems to arise with sets over 800 records in size..

Comment: I've moved this into the Meteor issue tracker. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/207

Comment: yes i noticed, thanks for that steve

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading Meteor.  I just tried this exact sample code in current master (at the time of writing 0.5.2).  I have the page open in all of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and my CPU usage is v. low.